# Правильное построение логики БД и php

Tags: php, mysql

На данный момент имеется:
БД:

> Таблица crm_products: id, title
>
> Таблица crm_ing: id, title
>
> Таблица crm_sales: *инфа о продаже*
>
> Таблица crm_sale_products: id, sale_id, product_id, count (связь продуктов со сделкой)
>
> Таблица crm_product_ings: id, product_id, ing_id, count (связь продукта с ингредиентами этого продукта, для отчетности по остатку)
>
> Таблица crm_ing_actions: id, ing_id, type_id, sale_id, count (при успешной сделке, сюда записываем, что ингредиенты ушли со склада, а также сюда записываем поставки и списания ввиду срока годности)

Логика проста - у каждого продукта есть ингредиенты, из которых этот продукт и состоит. При изменении статуса сделки на "успешная" берутся данные из crm_product_ings, затем они перемножаются на кол-во n продукта, затем в таблицу crm_ing_actions записываются id ингредиента, его кол-во, статус "продажа" и id продажи.

---

Проблема состоит в том, что у некоторых продуктов ингредиенты могут выбирать сами покупатели, т.е. они динамические. Для примера: большая шляпная коробка с цветами - статические элементы: большая коробка, лента, вода, пленка. Динамические - цветы (могут быть розы, пионы и т.д.)
Скажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать в такой логике? На данный момент инфа о продуктах пишется в таблицу crm_product_ings. Правильно ли будет сделать отдельную таблицу для динамических ингредиентов? Какая у нее должна быть логика? Кто примерно с таким сталкивался, какие решения тут есть?

Comment: мне вот даже читать лень. А нет схемы текущей БД?

Answer (score 0):

Две хлебных крошки:
1. В MySQL появилась возможность работать с полем типа JSON.
2. Большая шляпная коробка с цветами - цветы заданы где-то? Как ингредиенты. Не важно, пионы они, розы, или вообще гибриды кактуса и рододендрона - где-то они перечислены? Таблицу для динамических ингредиентов - да, можно. Хранить там имя и количество (остальные поля по вкусу).